# Junit capture Thread.sleep(10000); InterruptedException inside application in test?

Tags: java, multithreading, try-catch, junit5

I have a thread in my application that simulates working job
like this:

```
class FooJob {


public String work() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   
    return "1";
}
```

}

I'm causing this thread to kill with a small timeout with:

```
executor.invokeAll(callables,2c, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

All working well
The problem is in the Junit how can I capture this InterruptedException in the test?

I don't want to add exceptions to all the program hierarchy.

The exception I'm getting:

```
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.blah.myapp.FooJob .work()
```

I guess assertThatThrownBy not going to work here as this exception not thrown
is there any way in jUnit to capture this?

Comment: That an exception is thrown is an implementation detail that you should not check in tests. You may want to test the intended behaviours: the return value and may be (if important for you) the duration of the execution being shorter than 10s:

Comment: Re, "how can I capture this InterruptedException in the test?" By putting code to "capture" it in the `catch(...)` block in the `work()` method in your `FooJob` class?

Comment: what do you mean ? can you please give example ?

Comment: What do _You_ mean? What does "capture this InterruptedException" mean to you? Do you understand what the `e` stands for in `catch (InterruptedException e)`? (If not, then this is _way_ too soon in your Java language education for you to be messing around with threads.)

Comment: Threads is not the question , the question is how i test it in Junit

Comment: You mean, you want a test that proves that `e.printStackTrace()` really was called? As your `work()` function is written, you can't do that because `Thread.sleep()` is a static method and you have no control over what it throws. Best thing I can think of is, replace the `Thread.sleep()` call with `sleeper.sleep()` where `sleeper` is an instance that you inject. The _real_ `sleeper.sleep()` simply calls `Thread.sleep()`, but your test could inject a double for it that throws a mock exception. Then your test could ask the mock whether its printStackTrace() was called.

Comment: i have no such thing sleeper in java 8